# Convert Flux<List<T>> to List<T>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I'm invoking an asynchronous call to DB to fetch user related data, and collect it to a list as below

```
Mono<AppUser> user = email.flatMap(s -> appUserRepository.findByEmailLikeIgnoreCase(Mono.just(s)));
List<String> userAppRoles = new ArrayList<>();
user
   .map(AppUser::getApps)
   .subscribe(app -> app.forEach(x->userAppRoles.add(x.getAppRole())));
```

However the list "userAppRoles" is not getting populated.
I have to do it in a non-blocking way, so cannot use block() or get() methods which would eventually result in error as netty complains any blocking operation.

```
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {


        String path = exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath();
        String method = exchange.getRequest().getMethodValue();
        List<ApplicationData> appData = new ArrayList<>();
        Mono<String> email = oidcuserService.getUsername();

        Flux<Router> routes = routerRepository.findAll();
        Mono<AppUser> user = email.flatMap(s -> appUserRepository.findByEmailLikeIgnoreCase(Mono.just(s)));
        routes.filter(router -> router.getPolicies().containsKey(method))
                .map(Router::getPolicies)
                .map(p -> p.get(method))
                .subscribe(appData::addAll);

        List<String> routerAppNames = appData.stream().map(ads -> ads.getAppName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> routerAppRoles = appData.stream().map(ApplicationData::getAppRole).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> routerModuleRoles = appData.stream().map(ApplicationData::getModuleRole).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> routerPathcompRoles = appData.stream().map(ApplicationData::getPathCompRole).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> userAppRoles = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> userModuleRoles = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> userPathcompRoles = new ArrayList<>();

        user.map(AppUser::getAppsList).subscribe(applicationData -> applicationData.forEach(x->userAppRoles.add(x.getAppRole())));
        user.map(AppUser::getAppsList).subscribe(applicationData -> applicationData.forEach(x->userModuleRoles.add(x.getModuleRole())));
        user.map(AppUser::getAppsList).subscribe(applicationData -> applicationData.forEach(x->userPathcompRoles.add(x.getPathCompRole())));

    boolean appRoleFlag = userAppRoles.stream().filter(routerAppRoles::contains).collect(Collectors.toList()).isEmpty();
    boolean moduleRoleFlag = userModuleRoles.stream().filter(routerModuleRoles::contains).collect(Collectors.toList()).isEmpty();
    boolean pathCompRoleFlag = userPathcompRoles.stream().filter(routerPathcompRoles::contains).collect(Collectors.toList()).isEmpty();

    boolean result = appRoleFlag & moduleRoleFlag & pathCompRoleFlag;
        if(!result) {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            return response.setComplete();
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
```

Considering the comment below by Ricard Kollcaku that the entire code needs to be written in a functional way, how can compute multiple hot streams and return an output which boolean and not some stream.

Comment: What are you looking for is always blocking. because you are trying to block the stream to get some data. if you want to use reactive you should to do every part of it reactive in your case to return a Flux<String> if not than you should use imperative one

Comment: @RicardKollcaku Any suggestions on the edited question would be great.

Comment: First of all dont use any subscribe. return imediatly the stream.try to work inside the stream you can use .collectList() and then flatmap and work inside flatmap.
you can filter in 3 streams and collect them using Flux.zip in a flatmap and .onEmpty you can return in flatmap  return response.setComplete();.
in response you can return chain.filter(exchange) 
You can split it in small functions to be more understandable.

Comment: Appreciate it. Yes i have added too much code in one method, will refractor it.